# Example of sequence of characters that may _never_ appear in Python code?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, complexity-theory

This is a rather theoretical question, pertaining to the fundamental general syntax of Python.  I am looking for an example of sequence of characters (*1) that would **always** cause a syntax error when present inside a Python program, regardless of the context (*2).  For instance, the sequence `a[0)` is not a correct example, because the program

```
s = 'a[0)'
```

is perfectly valid.  What I want is a sequence of characters that, *wherever it occurs in the source code*, causes a syntax error!  (Oh, and of course, all the characters in this sequence have to be characters individually allowed to appear in a Python program).

**(edit: the following blockquoted example is wrong, since newlines may appear in triple-quoted strings.  Thanks to ekhumoro for this relevant remark!)**

> I suspect that the sequence “newline-quote-newline” is forbidden,
>   because the newline character may not appear in a quoted string: so,
>   if the first newline character does not causes a syntax error, this
>   means that the quote character starts a quoted string, and then the
>   second newline character will cause a syntax error.

It seems to me that a fundamentally buggy sequence could be
(edited some mistakes here: thanks to ekhumoro for noticing!)

```
␤'[)"[)'''[)"""[)'[)"[)'''[)"""[)
```

(where `␤` denotes a newline character), because one of the `[)`'s shall necessarily occur outside a quoted string, and the string cannot occur in a comment because of the initial `␤`.

However, I do not know enough about the sharp details of Python syntax to be sure that the above examples are correct: maybe there exists some bizarre context, more subtle than mere quoted strings, where the above sequences of characters would be allowed?  Maybe the full details of Python syntax even make it actually impossible to build any buggy sequence such as what I am looking for?…

**(edit added for more clarity)**
So, actually my question is about whether the specifications allow you to define a new kind of quoted context at some point: is there something in the Python specifications that say that the only possible quoted contexts are '…', "…", '''…''', """…""" and #…␤ (plus possibly a few more which I would not be currently aware of), or may you devise new quoted contexts as you wish?  Or maybe you could make your program start with a kind of codec, after which you would write the sequel of the program in an arbitrary language completely different from Python…?

(*1) In a first version of this question, I wrote “bytes” instead of “characters”, because I did not want to be bothered with bizarre Unicode characters; but that made possible to turn the question into encoding issues…  So, let us assume that we are working with a fixed encoding, whose set of admissible characters is fixed and well-known (say, ASCII for more simplicity).

(*2) FYI, the motivation of my question is to stress the difference between the language of a universal Turing machine (with self-delimited programs) and a general-purpose programming language, in the context of Kolmogorov complexity.

PS.:  Answers to the same question for other (interpreted) real-life languages also welcomed :-)

Comment: The sequence `" '"'''"""[)'"'''"""[) """` is valid, and includes your example. Also, triple-quoted strings can span multiple lines, so newline-quote-newline is not forbidden.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Damn it, all your comments are quite right: I missed all of these points in the initial version of my question… :-S  I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: This came up on Code Golf a few years back. See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133489/12647

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica  Terrific: this was exactly my question! 8-D  Please make you comment an answer so that I can validate it :-)